# Why is `less` just showing the output of my title script instead of the file contents?

Tags: less, csh

I'm using **csh** as my terminal and I have a script that runs when I change directories that replaces the window title with the current directory. I have it run initially in my *.cshrc* file as well so that it will change the window title in a new shell.

When I use `less` to view a text file within the console, instead of the file contents, I will see the output of this script. This effectively renders `less` useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by having the `~/.cshrc` file output things to the console which interfere with the operation of `less`.

One way to solve this is to check for interactive shells before doing anything that affects the console or changes the way that shell scripts would run (e.g., setting aliases for `cd`).

```
if ($?prompt) then
    # Do things that affect interactive shells here
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this FAQ](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#profileout) for Less on the developer homepage, it turns out that having anything that generates output to the console (which my window title script does) in the `.cshrc` file can interfere with the output of `less`. Apparently `less` invokes the shell to open and view files, and since any new instance of the shell will automatically execute the commands in `.cshrc`, whatever console output that occurs at that step will interfere with the tool's operation.

The solution is to remove the invocation of my script from the `.cshrc` file. I can put it into the `.login` file, but there is the caveat that any new invocation of the shell will not re-execute the commands in that file.